Can't access database to save information from jsp page
The stack trace is as follows:
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:478)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Root Cause

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:666)
    org.apache.jsp.add_005fstu_jsp._jspService(add_005fstu_jsp.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1334)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2084)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
    org.apache.jsp.add_005fstu_jsp._jspService(add_005fstu_jsp.java:151)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

This is the HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Student Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h2>Student Registration</h2>
        <form id="add_stu_form" action="add_stu.jsp" method="POST">
            
            <label for="enrol" style="color:black">Enrollment no:</label>
            <input type="text" name="enrol" id="enrol" placeholder="Enrollment Number" required>
            
            <label for="fullname" style="color:black">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required>
            
            <!--button type="submit">Add Student</button-->
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save"> 
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"> 
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Update"> 
            </p>
            <script></script>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

this is the jsp page:
<%-- 
    Document   : add_stu
    Created on : 08-Apr-2024, 11:06:07 pm
    Author     : DC
--%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
    Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ams","root","");
   
    long enrl = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("enrol"));
    String name = request.getParameter("fullname");
    Statement s0 = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs0 = s0.executeQuery("SELECT `No` FROM `stu_att`");
    int size = 0;
        while (rs0.next()) {
            size++;
        }
    int count = size + 1;
    int result;
    String sql;
    String button = request.getParameter("action");
    if("Save".equals(button)){
        sql = "INSERT INTO `stu_att`(`No`, `name`, `enrl`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps1.setInt(1, count);
        ps1.setString(2, name);
        ps1.setLong(3, enrl);
        result = ps1.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    else if("Delete".equals(button)){
        long del = enrl; //button2;
        sql = "DELETE FROM `stu_att` WHERE `enrl`=?";
        PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps2.setLong(1, del);
        result = ps2.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    else if("Update".equals(button)){
        long upd = enrl; //button2;
        sql = "UPDATE `stu_att` SET `name`='?' WHERE `enrl`=?";
        PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps3.setString(1, name);
        ps3.setLong(1, upd);
        result = ps3.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    else{
        result=001;
    }
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Add Student</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><%= result %> Record inserted!</p>
        <a href="">Back to home page</a>
    </body>
</html>


The code there looks OK. The error message thinks you're using MariaDB. Is that the case? (since your URLs and other code are for MySql)

@g00se the error message takes the ? literally, instead of taking the parameters into account.

You're calling the wrong executeUpdate methods. You need to call executeUpdate(), not executeUpdate(sql).

The error is not related to connecting the database, but to an error while trying to run
INSERT INTO `stu_att`(`No`, `name`, `enrl`) VALUES (?,?,?)

You are attempting to pass values to this command via
        PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps1.setInt(1, count);
        ps1.setString(2, name);
        ps1.setLong(3, enrl);
        result = ps1.executeUpdate(sql);

You will need to run ps1.execute() instead of ps1.executeUpdate(sql).
EDIT:
you will also need to make sure that you are using the correct driver via
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

and fix the way you get the connection:
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/ams", "root", "");


True - well spotted ;)

The execute method is mostly suited for DDL statements rather than DML. It is not appropriate in this case.

@RomanC to be fair neither is the executeUpdate version that accepts an argument, like the one OP is using.

@FedericoklezCulloca to be what?

@RomanC fair (missed an 'r')

@FedericoklezCulloca This version of executeUpdate does accept an argument but it doesn't accept parameters.

@RomanC That qualification is incorrect, execute() is for executing any statement, even if you don't know if it produces an update count, a result set, or multiple of those. executeUpdate() is for use when you know it produces an update count, and you are interested in that update count. In some JDBC drivers it might even be better for performance to call execute() instead of executeUpdate() (e.g. if their protocol requires an additional call or network roundtrip to determine the update count).

@MarkRotteveel The execute() method is from Statement but executeUpdate is from PreparedStatement. First one is more suited for DDL and single query execution. The second is for parametrized queries that boost the database performance via optimization, caching and batch processing. DML statements exactly this kind of usecase. If you need more information in comparison for performance see this question. So, it is correct.

@RomanC No, execute() and executeUpdate() are both from PreparedStatement. You're thinking of execute(String) (and executeUpdate(String)). You may also want to read the javadoc, which for execute() explicitly says "Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement." (emphasis mine)
